# In bibliography date is given as a year, n.d appears on the text

Tags: bibliographies

I have a code such as in .bib file:

```
@article{pff,
author = {Pfeffer,Fabian T. and Schoenia, Robert F. and Kennickell, Arthur and Andreski, Patricia },
title = {Measuring wealth and wealth inequality: Comparing
    two U.S. surveys},
journaltitle = {Journal of Economic and Social Measurement},
date = {2016},
}
```

and in the main text I have a code as:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{Title Here}
\author{Author Here}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
 textext \cite{pff} texttext
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref_q} 
\end{document}
```

What I desire is to get a reference in the text something like "Pfeffer, Schoeni, et al, 2016" while I am getting "Pfeffer, Schoenia, Kennickell & Andreski, n.d." . While in the "References" section reference seems perfectly fine, problem is obviously the absence of the year in text representation. I wonder how can I solve this.

PS: Beginner in LaTeX, or any coding and programming.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You probably want to use `year = {2016},`. `date` is biblatex terminology, and you are not using it.

Comment: Off-topic: You should encase the string `U.S.` in the `title` field in curly braces, i.e., write it as `{U.S.}`, to keep BibTeX from converting it to lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks Mico, both for your helpful answer and additional support you gave!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct field name -- at least as far as the `apacite` package and bibliography style are concerned -- is `year`, not `date`. And, while you're at it, you should change the field name `journaltitle` to `journal`.

After changing the field names, you need to perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX) in order to fully propagate the changes.